# ON YOUR BENEFIT

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to use the phrase:

> Use their information on your benefit.

It sounds wrong to me, I feel it should be:

> Use their information to your benefit

I also searched on google and found this:

> Use their information for your benefit

To me "for/to" sound correct, but not "On"

Is it correct to use it?

Comment: Nobody would use ***on*** in your context. [Both ***to*** and ***for***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+it+%2A+your+benefit&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cuse%20it%20%2A%20your%20benefit%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Buse%20it%20for%20your%20benefit%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Buse%20it%20to%20your%20benefit%3B%2Cc0) are fine, and mean the same.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard anyone say "on your benefit". You're correct that "for/to" are correct in this context.

For context, I am in the USA. Other areas do have meanings attached to "on your benefit" (see comments).

Comment: The word benefit can be used in different ways, a dictionary will list them.  "I'm on benefit at the moment"

Comment: ***Being on benefit*** is syntactically the same as being ***on drugs, on a winning streak, on holiday*** - the "surface metaphor" preposition ***on*** reflects the idea that benefit, drugs, winning streaks can be seen as "places" ("where" you are, what's supporting you). That preposition relates to ***being*** "somewhere", which isn't the same as ***using** [something] **for** [some purpose, some benefit, some reason]*.

Answer (score 1):

**Again a no context phrase**. These type of question are so difficult to answer.

It is highly probable that your phrase **Use their information on your benefit**. is correct. It is also likely to relate to data protection.

**Benefit is a social security payment system** in the UK, it takes a slightly different form in Northern Ireland and I doubt most U.S citizens are aware of it however the use of the word benefits does have the same meaning in the US

> **benefit noun (MONEY FROM GOVERNMENT)**

> the money given by the government to people who need financial help, for example because they cannot find a job:

Ref CED[Benefit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/benefit)

Examples

> If they could not prove they were looking for work, they could lose their benefit.

> Ref [nidirect.gov.uk](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/how-claim-benefit)..The different types of benefit.

> Benefits are available for people of working age, for pensioners, for families and children, and for people with disabilities and their carers.

> You won't owe state taxes **on your benefits** if you live in any of the 37 states that don't tax this income. Ref [investopedia.com](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/013015/how-can-i-avoid-paying-taxes-my-social-security-income.asp)

Comment: I think *it is highly **improbable** that OP's phrase "Use their information on your benefit"* is "correct" (not to beat about the bush, I don't think it could *ever* be valid). You can't just use "benefit" as a shorter alternative to a more meaningful noun phrase that could work in the cited context, such as ***benefit application form***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: How to claim benefit
The government has a range of benefits to provide opportunities and support. These are handled by various departments and agencies. If you are entitled to any of these benefits, you will need to claim them from the right place. "https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/how-claim-benefit"

Comment: @FumbleFingers:Who to ask about your benefit
Your nearest Jobs and Benefits office will help you with any questions you have about your benefits situation. Ref as above

Comment: @FumbleFingers: get advice "on your benefit" entitlement; https://www.eastlothian.gov.uk/info/210551/helping_you_stay_in_your_home/11870/money_advice_for_tenants/3

Comment: Could you please use the blockquote tools to format your answers? Just put a ">" before your examples or quoted lines, simple as that. I edit and reformat a lot of posts, but some of your posts are hard to read and I don't want to misformat them.

Comment: @ Eddie Kal♦ OK done

Comment: @Brad: You can *get advice **on*** almost any topic (the preposition associates with ***getting advice***, which is unrelated to the syntax of ***being on benefit[s], on the dole, on income support,...*** Those usages have nothing to do with the preposition involved in ***using something [prep] one's benefit, one's advantage, one's gratification***, where ***on*** is never appropriate.